# Android Studio for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I Have the following code and want to find out if there is any way i can put the following code into a `for` loop so that it is not so long as i am doing it a few times in my code

```
 if (Q1o1.equals("null")){
     button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
 }else{
     button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     button1.setText(Q1o1);
 }
 if (Q1o2.equals("null")){
     button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else{
     button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     button2.setText(Q1o2);
 }
 if (Q1o3.equals("null")){
     button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else{
     button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     button3.setText(Q1o3);
 }
 if (Q1o4.equals("null")){
     button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else{
     button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);button4.setText(Q1o4);
 }
 if (Q1o5.equals("null")){
     button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else{
     button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     button5.setText(Q1o5);
 }
 if (Q1o6.equals("null")){
     button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else{
     button6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     button6.setText(Q1o6);
 }
 if (Q1o7.equals("null")){
     button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else{
     button7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     button7.setText(Q1o7);
 }
```

Every if statement checks if the relevant variable that needs to be the button text is not null and then either hides it or puts that variable inside the button and shows the button. How can i make a for loop using different variables for each loop?

Comment: Please change your topic. This has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe declare arrays like this:

```
String[] stringArray = {*your strings here*};
ButtonView[] buttonArray = {*your buttons here*};
```

and a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    String thisString = stringArray[i];
    ButtonView thisButton = buttonArray[i];
    if(thisString.equals(null)){
        thisButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        thisButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        thisButton.setText(thisString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an array of the `Q1o7`'s, and an array of the buttons, then using a for loop between 0 and the length of the array, in which you will all the appropriate methods for the selected element in the array

Example:

First create the arrays:

```
Button[] buttonArray = {button1, .., button7}; //Replace the .. by the other buttons
String[] qoValues = {QO1, .., QO7} //As before
```

Now we create a loop that iterates over these arrays and calls the appropriate functions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < qoValues.length; i++) { //May also use buttonArray.length 
    ButtonView currentButton= buttonArray[i]; //get current value to work with
    String currentString = stringArray[i];
    if (currentString .equals("null")) { //Similar If statement construction as before
        currentButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        currentButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        currentButton.setText(currentString );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to define two Arralists where one is for buttons and the other is for variables :

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonsList = new ArraList<>();
```

add all your buttons to this list :

```
buttonsList.add(button1);
....
```

do the same for your variables and put them in another arraylist of strings

```
ArrayList<String> labelsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

your for loop should look like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); i++) {
    if(!labelList.get(i).equals("null")) {
        buttonsList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonsList.get(i).setText(labelList.get(i));
    } else {
          buttonsList.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```